# I'm trying to close a udp connection

Tags: c#

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2019, programming a server client connection.
When I've called my closing connection, the program throws a break null exception. I have tried different ways to log out of the UDP connection but none are working.

Here's my code that bugs the client:

```
this.clientSocket.SendTo(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, epServer);
```

When the program exits after this my server throws a socket exception when reconnecting.

CLIENT void

```
    public void Client_Closing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CLOSING SOCKET");

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLOSING SOCKET");
             
            // Initialise a packet object to store the data to be sent
            Packet sendData = new Packet();
            sendData.ChatDataIdentifier = DataIdentifier.LogOut;
            sendData.ChatName = this.name;
            sendData.ChatMessage = null;
                
            // Get packet as byte array
            byte[] byteData = sendData.GetDataStream();
               
            // Send packet to the server
            this.clientSocket.SendTo(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, epServer);   
              
            // Close the socket
            this.clientSocket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Closing Error: " + ex.Message, "UDP Client", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Console.WriteLine("Closing Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check whether epServer has value?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out Thanks for the help coder_b

I was calling my closing void from an event handler that runs if the client is closing.
and i had it set on a different instance of a class.

I instanced the event handler to the same object of the class that the socket is on and it worked here's the fixed code;

```
                AsynchronousClient AsynchronousClient = new AsynchronousClient();
            AsynchronousClient.StartClient();



            // Some boilerplate to react to close window event, CTRL-C, kill, etc
            //AsynchronousClient h = new AsynchronousClient(); //REMOVED THIS
            _handler += new EventHandler(AsynchronousClient.Handler); //FIXED HERE
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
```